Examples of using Principle of Deferred Decision
Reading the first lecture note from the Randomness & Computation course in Berekely, I came upon this "Principle of Deferred Decision". Looking at this question in MSE it seems that the term is used in Mitzenmacher and Upfal's book as well.
I am trying to demonstrate how to use this method, therefore, looking for some examples in which using this technique makes the solution easier.
Their example is to calculate the chance of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i = 0$ in a $\mathbb{Z}_p$ where $X_i$ are uniform random variables. They defer the decision on $X_n$ after deciding the values of other variables. Thus there will be only one value remaining for $X_i$ to be the solution to the given equation, making the probability $\frac1p$.
If you can think of other problems that can be solved with a similar technique, please share them with me.

These notes claim the principle of deferred decisions can show the probability of successfully completing Clock Solitaire is $\frac{1}{13}$ since it happens iff the final card of a permutation of $52$ cards is a King.
